# Is there a way of making my div background less and less transparent while user keeps scrolling the webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap webpage that uses video background. What is more, I'm using the following css code:

```
.transparent{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 999, 0, 1);
    overflow:hidden;

}

#imgBox{
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 1000px rgba(0, 999, 0, 1);

}
```

to make the "hole" in a covering layer, so that when user see's the layer - he only see a part of video underneath. It's hard to explain, so just take a look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/31/

I want to achieve an effect, that the green layer is transparent at the very beginning (let's say it has `rgba(0, 999, 0, 1)`, but when user keeps scrolling down and this layer becomes more and more visible, it gets less transparent (so when it's fully visible it should have `rgba(0,999,0,1)` for example.
How can I achieve it with jquery or css?

Comment: have you looked into CSS linear-gradient as a background image - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Comment: ...FYI, `rgba(0,999,0,1)` is not a valid color. The first 3 values range from 0-255. "999" is not an option here.

Comment: You probably made a typo in the line **(let's say it has rgba(0, 999, 0, 1)**, would you say _(let's say it has rgba(0, 999, 0, 0.1)_ instead ? Without mentionning that @BenPhilipp is true, max color value in `rgb()` or `rgba()` in CSS is 255.

Comment: I am not sure about your requirement but checkout this updated jsfiddle of your's http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/36/

Comment: @akshayk that solved my problem! please post it as an answer so I can accept it, thanks!

Comment: I have posted it as answer with the explanation of code changes and working of code... @randomuser1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about your requirement but checkout this updated jsfiddle of your's

Just added `$("#black").css("opacity",$("body").scrollTop()/1000);` in `$(window).scroll` such that it will increase the opacity on window scroll and I am using very small amount since the value of opacity can be only withing the range of 0 to 1

http://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/36/

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `$(window).scroll` function in JQuery, detect scrolling direction and according to that, adjust the opacity with rgba like that:

```
$("#greenbox").css("background-color", "rgba(0, 999, 0, "+opacity+")");
```

Comment: Using the color values you mentioned, but it is invalid.