# How can I use properly the $("body").scrollTop() in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is actually a follow up to my previous question https://stackoverflow.com/a/31721869/4662074 . I want to achieve the effect that when user scrolls down the page, next divs will change the opacity so that will be covering the main video as long as user keeps scrolling the webpage. Here's the example https://jsfiddle.net/Leytgm3L/38/ - when you see it on full screen then it works nice, but when the window is smaller - then the section does not cover fully the video beneath it - I have to keep scrolling to make its opacity to 100%. How can I cover the video completely when it's reached? I think the problem lies in this line:

```
    $("#black").css("opacity",$("body").scrollTop()/1000);
```

and actually in this value `$("body").scrollTop()`. How can I fix that?

Comment: Why not use `window.scollY` instead of `$("body").scrollTop()`? That might help.

Comment: This would be more cross browser friendly AFAIK: `$(document).scrollTop()`

Comment: @evolutionxbox hey, I tested your solution, but it didn't do the trick :(

Comment: @A.Wolff same as above, I tried this too and it didn't work..

Comment: Sorry buddy. I'm on my phone.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, it is working for me

```
$("#black").css("opacity",$("body").scrollTop()/($("#black").offset().top*2.5));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vinodmurukesan/Leytgm3L/39/

Comment: thanks, but when I run your code in full screen mode - this is what I get http://i.imgur.com/5ifnwQX.png and at this point I wanted to have the background completely black, and when user scrolls a little up then it becomes more and more transparent. Could you help me with that?

Comment: Please check this and let me know https://jsfiddle.net/vinodmurukesan/Leytgm3L/48/